# Kotlin/Native project built without errors, but fails to run

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I create a Kotlin/Native project with gradle init, and follow the instructions from here, managed to build the project without problems, being generated a `build/bin/native/debugExecutable/executable.kexe` executable file.

But when I try to run the project, I got the message:

`/build/bin/native/debugExecutable/executable.kexe: error while loading shared libraries: libone.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I am using a C library, located in the directory `../libone/libone.so` (relative to the project folder). I have this `*.dex` file on the directory `src/nativeInterop/cinterop` of my project:

```
headers = libone.h
package = libone

compilerOpts.linux = -I/.../libone
linkerOpts.linux = -L/.../libone -lone
```

I have tried put the executable (`executable.kexe`) and the library (`libone.so`) in the same directory, but do not work either (same error occurs). What I am missing here?

**UPDATE** I made work manually setting the linux environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the library directory. I wonder if I could make work without this change in the system.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.5.31'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    def hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    def isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    def nativeTarget
    if (hostOs == "Mac OS X") nativeTarget = macosX64('native')
    else if (hostOs == "Linux") nativeTarget = linuxX64("native")
    else if (isMingwX64) nativeTarget = mingwX64("native")
    else throw new FileNotFoundException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")

    nativeTarget.with {
        compilations.main { // NL
            cinterops {     // NL
                libone     // NL
            }               // NL
        }                   // NL
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = 'main'
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        nativeMain {

        }
        nativeTest {

        }
    }
}
```

**Makefile for libone**

```
all: libone

libone: libone.o
    gcc -shared -o libone.so libone.o -Wl,--out-implib,libone.a

libone.o: libone.c
    gcc -fPIC -c libone.c -o libone.o
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the absolute path in the .def file as a linker option? My guess is that relative paths might be the root cause here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the path in the def file to an absolute path, in my project I usually generate the def dynamically and make it a gradle task. But I still recommend you to use absolute paths anyway, there are enough examples here [kotlin native samples](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/kotlin-native/backend.native/tests/samples)